# action after all of AJAX request finish

Tags: jquery, ajax

I trying to execute an action after the ajax, but I can't

```
$.each(LinkUnique,function(i){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://xxxx.net/',
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg.indexOf("http://") !=-1)
                    link = link+msg+"\n";
            }
        });
    });
```

Here the next action after the script:

```
alert("Finish");
```

`async: false` isn't a good option because my page stops completely.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably trying to wait until all the ajax calls have completed, as you're doing multiple :

```
var xhrs = [],
    link = '';

$.each(LinkUnique,function(i){
    var xhr = $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url : 'http://xxxx.net/'
              }).done(function(msg) {
                  if(msg.indexOf("http://") !=-1)
                      link = link+msg+"\n";
              });

    xhrs.push(xhr);
});

$.when.apply($, xhrs).then(function() {
    alert(link);
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #XMLHttpRequest has no method 'done'

Comment: @user758499 - too old jQuery !