# How to set a counter and flag based on ajax reply not disabling async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a form field having a number of inpute text fields. Some of the fields expect some similar kind of data, and thus I gave them a common class. The requests are handled using ajax. For each input field, the request is passed separately, using a `.each(function()` for input fields. Below is a base code;

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){

  var flag1 = 0;
  var flag2 = 0;

  $('.input_text_field').each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    var curvalue = current.val();
    if(curvalue != ""){

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaxhandler.php',
        data: 'item='+curvalue,
        cache: false,
        async: false,//would like to remove this
        success: function(result) {
          if(result == "true"){
            flag1++;
          }else{
            flag2 = 1;
          }
        }
      });

    }
  });

  if(flag2 == 0 && flag1 > 0){ //this happens before the ajax request(s) completes (if asyc:true), I think.
    alert(flag1);
  }else{
    alert("false, "+flag1);
  }

});
```

The ajax replies may be either "true" or "false". I would like to count the "true" replies, and also would like to set a flag if there is any "false" reply. Inorder to achive this, I used 2 local flags (bothe has value 0 initially), `flag1` (for counting the "true" replies) and `flag2` (to identify if there is any false reply).

I want to do something if `(flag2 == 0 && flag1 > 0)`. In order to make `flag1` increment, I set `async: false`, but I got a lot of feedbacks that disabling `async` is not a good practice, so I would like to get rid of it. Is there any way to achieve the same without disabling `async`?

Comment: You have to code "around" the asynchronous behaviour, there are no easy fixes, the only solution is to use callbacks / promises, and do whatever it is you're doing after the ajax call, async:false certainly isn't the answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [action after all of AJAX request finish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314364/action-after-all-of-ajax-request-finish)

Comment: @FelixKling : The link that you posted doesn't have any accepted answers.

Comment: @harsha: So? The answer is still the correct one (and given by adeneo btw). You can also find a question with an accepted answer if you like, this question has come up several times already, and `$.when.apply(null, promises)` is almost always the answer.

Comment: @FelixKling : No offense , but that is the usual reply I get when I post a link without accepted answers on SO, which made me think that might be a necessity! Again , no offense meant :-)

Comment: why can't you send all data at once and respond with json , then match json to elements on the response?

Comment: @harsha: Well, then you can tell those people that only because didn't care to accept the answer, doesn't mean it isn't correct or a duplicate. I'd also tend to find questions with accepted answers, but if there is at least one highly upvoted answer, it should suffice. And: None taken :)

Answer (score 0):

Now, I haven't tried this code, you might have to tweak it some, but I think something along these lines would work:

```
 var getData = function( val ){
 return {
        $.ajax('ajaxhandler.php', {
        data: { value: val },
        dataType: 'json'});
  }
}

$('#mybutton').click(function(){
  var flag1 = 0;
  var flag2 = 0, deferreds = [];
  $('.input_text_field').each(function(){
   var currentVal = $(this).val();
   if(!!currentVal){
    deferreds.push(getData(curvalue).then(function(resp){
    (resp == "true") ? flag1 += 1 : flag2 = 1;
    }));
  }//End if
 }); //End each
$.when.apply(window, deferreds).then(function(){
    //put callback code here
     if(flag2 == 0 && flag1 > 0){ 
       alert(flag1);
        }else{
           alert("false, "+flag1);
         }
      });
   });//End click
```

Not sure why you would loop through the input fields and ajax individually though vs serializing the form and send it all at once. But Im sure you have a good reason for what you are trying to do.

Again, I haven't tried this code. I just wrote this up on my mobile phone. But theoretically it should work.

Comment: Where is the code that gets executed once all the requests are done? Not that using `$.when` is unnecessary in your example. You could just use `getData(curvalue).then(...)`.